# Kotlin JS - Accessing HTML DOM properties

Tags: kotlin

What is the canonical way to access HTML DOM properties in Kotlin. I don't see some of the dom properties like `offsetHeight` & `offsetWidth` exposed in the `Element`

```kotlin
var e : Element? = document.getElementById("text")
e.offsetHeight //Error
```

Comment: The Kotlin.dom project is also making it easier to access DOM from both Kotlin JVM and Kotlin JS code: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.dom

Answer (score 4):

Just cast `e` to `HTMLElement`, so it gets all the properties you would expect.

```
(e as HTMLElement).offsetHeight
```

It is not a feature of Kotlin, I found this in a normal JS documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

**ALSO**

You are right to ask about a 'canonical' way to do things, since Kotlin is quite different from JavaScript internally. Here is how I would do your code snippet:

```
val e = document.getElementById("text")!! as HTMLElement
e.offsetHeight
```

1. Use `val` instead of `var` in your code. It states for a fixed reference and allows some code optimizations. http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields
2. Don't use nullable types like `Element?` if you don't need it. In this case you may be pretty sure about your DOM structure, so `getElementById("text")` must return an element, not a null. Put a null-assertion `!!` there to easy your mind. In case that your JS works with an unknown html, I would handle the situation better:

   ```
   val e = document.getElementById("text") as? HTMLElement ?: throw RuntimeException("the DOM has no 'text' id")
   ```

Comment: I believe you always better to use ?: throw otherwise you will get useless error message that will difficult to find out

Comment: @SureshG Did that help you? If so, please accept the answer.